# python code- "memory limit exceeded" for larger test cases

Tags: python

Alice got a message M. It is in an alien language. `A` string in an alien language is said to be valid if it contains the letter a or `z`. Alice decided to count the number of valid substrings of the message `M`. Help him to do this. Two substrings are different if it occurs at different positions in the message.

Input
First line of the input contains the number of test cases `T`. It is followed by `T` lines. Each line has a single string `M`.

Output
For each test case, output a single number, the number of valid substrings.

Constraints

```
|M| <= 10^6
```

`M` contains only lower case latin latters, that is characters `a` to `z`.
Time Limit: 5.0 sec(s) for each input file.
Memory Limit: 256 MB
Source Limit: 1024 KB
Marking Scheme: Score is assigned if any testcase passes.

MY CODE:

```
t=int(input())
s=[]
for k in range(t):
    s=input()
    count=0
    if ("a" in s) or ("z" in s):
        res=[s[i:j] for i in range(len(s)) for j in range(i+1, len(s)+1)]
        for w in range(len(res)):
            if ("a" in res[w]) or ("z" in res[w]):
                count+=1
    print(count)
```

I have wrote the above code in python the first test case was executed but when I submitted the code it displayed the message "memory length exceeded" can any one reduce the execution time and memory consumption of the code?

Comment: where are your test cases?

Comment: You don't need to build a list of all substrings to iterate over them - this takes O(n^3) memory. You also don't need to iterate over them, since that's too slow. You need to think of an efficient algorithm to solve the problem, that is the point of the challenge; brute force is not good enough. Your whole approach is unsalvageable and you need to go back to the drawing board.

Comment: I would post an answer but without test cases I can't know if it is right or if it works as intended